# Making USB drives readonly on an specific USB port or for an user account

Tags: linux, usb, usb-drive, readonly

I have a Multiseat machine and the second seat has USB access from a signle port by HUB (a Keyboard and a mouse are connected to it).
I need make all storages drives that is connected to to this HUB be read-only.
This seat logins only by one user account.

How can I make a USB port read-only for one Account or one port (without makeing problem for Input devices that are connected it that port)?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks